# Extract list from a Pandas ExponentialMovingWindow

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to extract the underlying list/array from a Pandas ExponentialMovingWindow?

```
window = pd.Series.ewm(df, alpha)
window.mean() // works
window.sum() // works
window.getattr('array') // does NOT work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by underlying list/array you mean the data after ewm, then `Data =  window.obj` should work

Comment: AttributeError: 'ExponentialMovingWindow' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: window.obj gives me the original series I am using, in your case df
Is that what you want?

Comment: window.obj did the trick. Thank you!